# displaying a dynamic octagon using PHP

Tags: php, graphics, gd, formula, gdlib

Hello Stackoverflow community,

for a little game I need to display an octagon ([Like this one](http://de.narutopedia.eu/images/a/a4/Skill_kakashi.gif))

The shape adapts itself to certain values I get from the database. My Problem is, I have absolutely no idea how to launch into it. I neither know the formula for my purpose, nor I know how I could draw such a shape in PHP.

In general I'm relatively good at PHP. So I`d be happy about theoretical approaches to a solution and not necessarily code =)

Thanks in advance

Comment: google is ur friend my friend :-)

Comment: @Neal I tried google first =) Couldn't find anything about this topic. Could you give me a hint =D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whipped this up.  It calculates the coordinates for you already, but you can easily specify your own coordinates in the **$vertices** array (and remove the generation).

```
<?php
$radius = 100;
$sides = 8;

$points = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $sides; $i++) {
    $points[] = round( $radius * cos($i*2 * pi() / $sides) + $radius );  // x
    $points[] = round( $radius * sin($i*2 * pi() / $sides) + $radius );  // y
}



// Draw the image.
$im = imagecreate($radius*2 + 10, $radius*2 + 10);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);  // White background

imagefilledpolygon($im, $points, $sides, $black);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a formula for this, but once you figured one out you can make use of the [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) extension and draw your shape.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html) Supports this, and is fairly easy to use. 
[Example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0%3a|Nin|Tai|Gen|Ken|Riki|Soku|Sei|In&chxt=x&chs=300x300&cht=r&chco=C02020&chd=t:100,90,80,90,70,90,60,100,100&chls=2,9,0&chm=B,FF000080,0,0,0)